# Modeling daily purchase events / website traffic, time series or independent events?

Tags: time-series, modeling, dataset, poisson-regression

I've been thinking about how best to model sequential events like purchases on a website, or website traffic.  I'm curious if people think this is best modeled as a poisson process (or something like that), or as a time series model, or both depending on the use case.

On the one hand formal time series models don't seem to quite fit with the underlying process that's going on with web traffic / buys. Unlike what I think of as traditional time series data sets (stocks, populations) those things intuitively have a temporal dependency (stock prices rarely randomly fluctuate around a mean).

However things like web traffic **may** have temporal dependency (it's unlikely I'll come back and buy something today if I bought something yesterday, or I may go to a website every day to read it, like Axios.com). Given a sufficiently large population of potential traffic, independence may be a reasonable assumption.

I don't have any specific problem I'm solving at the moment, more just thinking about how one models data that is collected longitudinally that may not have an actual temporal dependence in the underlying data 
generating process.

Here's a quick bit of code illustrating 2 hypothetical web traffic time series:

```
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)

d <- seq(ymd("2018-06-01"),ymd("2018-09-01"),by='days')
## Poisson process
y1<- rpois(length(d),100)

## AR 1
y2 <- round(100 + arima.sim(list(order=c(1,0,0), ar=.5), n=length(d), sd = 10))


df = data.frame(date = rep(d,2), val = c(y1,y2) ,
type = c(rep("Poisson",length(d)),rep("AR",length(d))) )

ggplot(df,aes(x = date, y = val, group = type, color = type)) + 
geom_line() + theme_bw()
```

[image: Fun Picture]

Comment: you could maybe start with a simple model, like poisson regression with weekdays as regressors (and some other relevant regressors), calculate residuals, then calculate autocorrelation function of residuals (assuming daily data). Then show us a plot of the estimated autocorrelation function